# Create list from for-loop answers

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have this simple code

```
n=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

for i in n:
  x=i+5
  print (x)
```

the answer will be like this

```
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

the question is:

how can i make python return the answer in a list like this `[5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]` ??

Answer (score 3):

You can declare a list

```
new_list = []
```

and inside the loop, use `append()` method to add the element:

```
for i in n:
    x = i + 5
    new_list.append(x)
```

You can also do this by *list comprenhension*:

```
new_list = [i + 5 for i in n]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension is quite simple:

```
n=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

result = [i+5 for i in n]

print(result)
```